# How to modify the Adobe CQ ActivatePageProcess process

Tags: aem

I'm working with Adobe Experience Manager version 5.6 (CQ).  I have a requirement that involves modifying the ActivatePageProcess workflow process, basically checking who the user is that is trying to publish, and actually opening the document for edit if it's not an administrator.  The issue I'm having is that I'm not clear where I can find the ActivatePageProcess script in CRXDE ... or if it's even there.  Once I find it, I know I can move it to /apps and make my changes, but so far I'm not able to find it at all.  Can anybody give me some guidance?

Thanks very much in advance, Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process component can be found here:

```
/libs/wcm/workflow/components/workflow/activateresourceprocess
```

Please notice it's only an invoker of the [`ActivatePageProcess`](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/workflow/process/ActivatePageProcess.html) OSGi component.

However, I'm not sure if it a correct approach to achieve your goal. This process is used to *activate* some resource, but it isn't an activation event listener. Modifying it won't change the activation behaviour.

What you can do:

- use [replication preprocessor](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/Preprocessor.html) to prevent user from activating content (you can't redirect user to anything, though),
- tweak sidekick/WCM ExtJS code and add there some additional logic to the activation action,
- above WCM ExtJS code hits `/bin/replicate` servlet (Firebug will give you more details). You can write a servlet filter to intercept activation requests and send redirect is the user has insufficient privileges.

Comment: I ended up going with the second option above, which requires modifying the /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/wcm/SiteAdmin.Actions.js file - look for CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.activatePage.  Tomek - dziekuje!

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would remove replicate permissions for your Authors, and then modify the OOTB Activate WF step to include whatever logic you need. the Replication servlet that is called when a user clicks Activate (or Deactivate) will invoke the OOTB WF model if the users dont have permissions to replicate the content.