# Proper User and Notifications for Workflow de/activation

Tags: workflow, aem

We have a multi site setup with separate content trees with their own groups and users. The 4-eye principle is strictly enforced, so no user has replication rights.

The limitation of CQ is that if a user with no replication rights clicks on the activate button in SiteAdmin or the Sidekick, the Default Request for Activation workflow gets triggered. This is hardcoded and cannot be changed; the same is valid for deactivation. So what I did is to create a custom workflow step which I placed as the only step into the default workflows. This custom step checks the path of the workload item and triggers the correct workflow for this tree.

**First problem:** As this step is directly completed and a new workflow is triggered, the user that started the workflow, immediatly gets the message that the workflow is completed. Can I somehow have the second workflow be a subtask so the initial workflow only gets completed when the subtask is completed?

**Second problem:** The tree specific workflow has one approver step, followed by a custom 4-eye-check step (if the last modified user equals the approver, the workflow steps back to the approver step with an error) and the last step is the `com.day.cq.wcm.workflow.process.ActivatePageProcess`. But as no user has replication rights the checkbox "Replicate As Participant" is not selected. Thus each page has `admin` as the `cq:lastReplicatedBy`. Is it somehow possible to have the approver set without him having replicaton rights?

Code Snippet of our forking workflow:

```
protected void processItem(WorkItem item, WorkflowSession wfSession, WorkflowData workflowData, String config) throws WorkflowException {
    ResourceResolver resolver = getResourceResolver();
    PageManager pm = resolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
    try {
        String path = workflowData.getPayload().toString();
        Page page = pm.getContainingPage(path);
        if (page != null) {
            //calculate the id of the correct model depending on page
            String wfid = getWfId(page);
            WorkflowModel mmodel = wfSession.getModel(wfId);
            wfSession.startWorkflow(model, workflowData);
        }
    } finally {
        closeResourceResolver(resolver);
        wfSession.terminateWorkflow(item.getWorkflow());
    }
}
```

ps. This is a combined question regarding our special workflow setup. If some moderator thinks I should ask two seperate questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

This is very interesting case!

**First problem:**

**CQ5.6 and further:**
In the `Day CQ Workflow Email Notification Service` configuration, there are check boxes that allow to turn off notification on abort or complete.

**CQ5.5:**

- **option 1** You can turn off both notifications (abort & complete) by leaving `event.topic` empty in the very same service configuration ( `Day CQ Workflow Email Notification Service`)
- **option 2** (the bad way) You can remove the template that is used for generation of that email. (`/etc/workflow/notification/email/default/en.txt`) This will cause two things:

  1. Email won't be sent anymore.
  2. You will have ugly stack traces in your logs. However, by proper logging configuration these stack traces can be removed from the main error.log.

**Second problem**: I would go for the easiest way and on CRX level change the value of cq:lastReplicatedBy field afterwards. Any other way would be too complicated in my opinion. (and each solution would be just a workaround, I don't think that there is a clean solution for that)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try the solution for the second problem. For the first, I think we have somehow disabled email notifications.

Comment: Could you share the solution for disabling email notifications? Im interested in your approach for that.

Comment: There is an OSGi Service for Workflows where you can disable the emails: Day CQ Workflow Email Notification Service
There you can say if an email is sent on abort and/or completion

Comment: There are not such checkboxes on CQ5.5, but leaving event.topic empty in the same service does the trick! I will edit my answer for the sake of future visitors.

Comment: Ok, then maybe this was added with 5.6 or 5.6.1, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Any workflow model is customizable so you can have your own process doing the tasks. You can add whatever logic before invoking the default workflow steps. Also see this [How to modify the Adobe CQ ActivatePageProcess process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859556/how-to-modify-the-adobe-cq-activatepageprocess-process)

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't very useful regarding my specific question. As I wrote I already customized the default de/activation workflow and have custom steps.